# uploadify - rename uploaded file 

Tags: php, uploadify

Hy , i was looking at uploadify.php and did'n understand a thing.

I have a form like this :

```
<form id="formid" name="upload_pic" action="upload.php">
<select name="product_id">
<option value="1">Apples</option>
<option value="2">Oranges</option>
... etc
</select>
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
</form>
```

and my uploadify settings are :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '../images/level3/tabv_all/tab_header/',
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg',
    'fileDesc'    : 'ONLY JPG (.JPG)',
    'removeCompleted' : false
  });
});
</script>
```

What i want to do is that if the user select `Apples` wich has the `id=1` and `browse for a file like Tasty_apples.jpg`  -> the uploaded file to  be renames to `product@1@Tasty_apples.jpg` and then to be inserted in mysql like that?

The main question is how to add the extra `product@id@` to a file based on a `<select><option> value` ?

Thank you very much

The uploadify.php is this :

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to hand control over your server-side filenaming to a client-side script. This kind of filename manipulation should be done on the SERVER, under the php script's control.

Comment: I agree .. but how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send additional data to your backend script with scriptData option:

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/

Example

```
var selectedID = $("select[name=product_id]").val()

'scriptData'  : {'pid': selectedID}

// uplodify.php
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . 'product@' . $_POST['pid'] . '@' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

Comment: OK but how about renamed file ?

Comment: I don't even know how to read that uploaded file name in the post processing .. ?

Answer (score 2):

I think i have solved this...try this in your upload.php file

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$newName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['folder'];
if(file_exists($targetPath."/".$newName))
         {
         //echo "test";exit;
            $part=explode("." , $newName);
            $name1=$part[0];
            $ext=$part[1];
            $newName=$name1."_".rand().".".$ext;
        }
$Path = $targetPath . '/';
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$Path) . $newName;
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

it would be good if you could provide your actual 'uploadify.php' file, to help with the actual PHP. But as an example of how you would go about changing the name it would be something along the lines of this:

```
$tmp_name = @$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

$name = @$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

$filesize = @$_FILES['Filedata']['size'];

$extension  = strtolower(pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$newname = 'apples&'.$name . "." . $extension ;
```

This is just an example, if I had your code I could point it out better; but hope that's understandable!

Comment: the uploadify.php is the standard one that came with the script

Comment: Don't use the error suppression operator `@` for this sort of thing. If there's an upload error, you'll just end up with bad data and no clue of what happened.

Comment: And add an additional parameter to your uploadify config: `'scriptData'  : {'product_id': $('select[name=product_id]').val()}` so you can reach category id by `$_REQUEST["product_id"]` on the server. So new name will be `$newname = $cat_name.'@'. (int)$_REQUEST["product_id"].'@'. $name "." . $extension ;`

Comment: The `product_id` can be reached with `$_POST['product_id']` why to add it to the `scriptData` ? To be used on `uploadify.php`? My mind is gone .. is complete chaos in my head ... :(

Comment: And another question is : on my postprocessing file `upload.php` how to retrieve the uploadify uploaded file name ?

Comment: I usually just console.log the data if something goes wrong and debug that way, so using the '@' doesn't affect me however I would suggest following your advice.

Comment: @pufos I'm assuming you mean how to retrieve the image you uploaded on another page? You would have to save the image along with an identifier so later on you could do 'SELECT image FROM images WHERE identifier = 'apple' as an example.

Comment: I've posted my uploadify.php script ... Can you point out where exactly should i make the changes . I understood i will pass the `product_id` with scriptData or dynamic with `.uploadifySettings()` .. how about the post-processing in `uploadify.php` .. Thank`s a lot.

Comment: @9miles Not that ... my form process page is `upload.php` wich is different from `uploadify.php` ... In that `upload.php` i will check for `$_POST[]` and then make an `INSERT INTO`. How to read the `<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload">` . Does `uploadify` set the file name that was uploaded to that `<input>` field to be retrieved with `$_POST['file_upload']` ?

Comment: you can get uploadify to put the filename into a hidden field such as 'imagename'. within the javascript of uploadify you need to specify the settings for this so: 

callback: { nameField: settings.nameField || "#imagename" }

the hidden input field will then get the value of of the image. Put a name on the field too called 'imagename' and you will be able to access this with $_POST['imagename']

Comment: `$cats = array(1=>'apples',2=>'oranges');
if (!empty($_FILES)) { // no target path included
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $name = @$_FILES['Filedata']['name']; $extension  = strtolower(pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); $newname = (isset($cats[$_REQUEST["product_id"]]) ? $cats[$_REQUEST["product_id"]] : "catnotexist" ).'@'. (int)$_REQUEST["product_id"].'@'. $name "." . $extension ;
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,'path/'.$newname);
    echo $newname;
}`

Comment: @9miles the thing is that i don't understant how uploadify works at it's core .. So i can't do the best custom made uploadify. The thing i don't understand is .. what's with the `$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];` why `'tmp_name'` ... or `$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];` what's the differences ?

Comment: @atma please write an answer for better understanding .. this looks creepy like this ...

Comment: tmp_name is just a random name that is assigned to a temporary file, it's then deleted at the end of the script. Just used to reference throughout the script as that name is never changed within the script...

Answer (score 1):

```
//your categories array, example
$cats = array(1=>'apples',2=>'oranges');

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. trim($_REQUEST['folder'], '/') . '/';
  $name = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $newname = (isset($cats[$_REQUEST["product_id"]]) ? $cats[$_REQUEST["product_id"]] : 'category_not_exist' ).'@'. (int)$_REQUEST["product_id"].'@'. $name '.' . $extension;
  $targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $newname;
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
  echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile); 
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to check the target directory: `if (!is_dir($targetPath)) @mkdir($targetPath,0775,true);`

Comment: super answer : i did'n know about the `@mkdir` ... cool ... Thank you